# CSS works for other browser ,but not working in internet explorer

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I have the following css which in chrome, firstfox and Edge centers an absolutely positioned image

```
<div runat="server" id="Logo" class="MasImg">&nbsp;</div>

.MasImg {
 position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url('../images/pm_image.png');
    background-position-x: center;
}
```

However in internet explorer 11 this doesn't center the image. Instead the image stays on the right side of the container div. My question is, how can I make my script above work in ie11?

Comment: is it the div or the background image that is on the right in ie?  could you create a [mcve] as with the current code, it is unclear what your issue is

Comment: @Pete I am adding my div here

Comment: @Pete I have added my DIV in my question

Comment: I made a sample to test but it has the same result in IE and Edge. The result is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/egMoz.png. Could you please provide a code snippet which can **reproduce the issue**? I think there might be some parts missing in your code which leads to the issue can't be reproduced.